# VB.NET: Creating new form and then editing controls of that form

Tags: windows, vb.net, multithreading, forms, for-loop

I am trying to create a new form from a thread with the following:

```
Dim NewGameForm as New GameForm
NewGameForm.ShowDialog()
```

After I make the new form, I want to change a label on that form with the following:

```
NewGameForm.Label1.Text = "This is new text"
```

However, I am unable to change the contents of this label after the form is shown with ShowDialog().  Help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So change the label before showing the form?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange your codes,that's all :

```
Dim NewGameForm as New GameForm
NewGameForm.Label1.Text = "This is new text"
NewGameForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks Zack! However, I need to be able to change the content in the controls of each new form after it is made.  Is there a way to do this?  I found a work-around for now, but just curious if there may be a better way.